# How to show message to the snackBar when user does not have internet in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

if internet connection is off i want to show "No internet connection" message in SnackBar.
if internet connection is on it will show UI.
This is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
class InternetCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InternetState createState() => _InternetState();
}

class _InternetState extends State<InternetCheck> {
  bool _isInternet = true;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  checkInternet() async {
    try {
      final response = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com'); // google
      if (response.isNotEmpty && response[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        _isInternet = true; // internet
        setState(() {});
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      _isInternet = false; // no internet
      setState(() {
        _showSnackBar();
      });
    }

    return _isInternet;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkInternet();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _showSnackBar() {
    SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('No Connection'));
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // checkInternet();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: _isInternet == true ? Text('internet') : Text('no Internet'),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

using my code when app run first time with internet off it show SnackBar but when i switch internet on and again switch internet off then it will not showing snakbar.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package. It allows you to listen for network state changes :

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    if(connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none)
        _showSnackbar();
  })
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin

Comment: Well, you're gonna be pretty limited in your Flutter development then. Not only is connectivity a "Flutter favorite" (approved by the Flutter team), it is maintained by the  team themselves.

Comment: you have any suggestion, what I can do

Comment: Use the package. Add `connectivity: ^0.4.9` to your dependencies in pubscpec.yaml and run `flutter pub get`. Then add `import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';` in the beginning of your code and you will be able to use the code in my answer.